# What is wrong in the function declaration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Explain to me, please, in what a mistake in the declaration/description of this method?

```
class Set
{
    struct Node {
        // ...
    };
    // ...
    Node* &_getLink(const Node *const&, int) const;
    // ...
};

Node* &Set::_getLink(const Node *const &root, int t) const
{
    // ...
}
```

I don't see mistakes, but the compiler (MS VS C++) gives out many syntax errors.

Comment: try Set::Node to your code

Comment: What is the compiler error? Put it in the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to fully qualify the name of `Node` (which is defined in the scope of `Set`):

```
    Set::Node* &Set::_getLink(const Node *const &root, int t) const
//  ^^^^^
```

Without the fully qualification, the compiler will look for a global type named `Node`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a scoping one. You need to prefix `Node` here:

```
Set::Node* &Set::_getLink(const Node *const &root, int t) const
{
    // ...
}
```

Indeed, `Node` is unknown at the time it is encountered (you are at namespace scope, not inside `Set`'s scope). You can also use `auto`:

```
auto Set::_getLink(const Node *const &root, int t) const -> Node *&
{
    // ...
}
```

After `->`, you are at `Set`'s scope and `Node` is known.

Answer (score 0):

you dont define Node in global scope
so use this code

```
//by Set::Node we give compiler that this function exist in class Node
Set::Node* &Set::_getLink(const Node *const &root, int t) const
{
   // ...
}
```